# Obj-C Date - If earlier, make it tomorrow

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, date-arithmetic, nsdatecomponents

I have an NSDate object, and I need to check if it has already passed. If so, turn that date into the date of tomorrow, but I can't lose information like TimeZone in the process.

Could you plz help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate` has no timezone info. It's just a thin layer over the number of seconds elapsed since its epoch. You can use a calendar and a timezone to turn it into an `NSDateComponents`, fiddle with the date there, and then format that into a new `NSDate`.

Comment: ive found something about it... but i haven'f found a war to to replace components in a date only add.

Comment: See `-[NSDateComponents setDay:]` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *date = ...;
if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date] > 0) {
    date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:24*60*60];
}
```

Comment: Right, I think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: ...But this answered my unvoiced question about how to do date arithmetic so thanks!